# how to make first name & last name inline?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have this code and in this form I want the first name & last name next to each other how can I do that? I saw some tutorials but in that they are showing to make the whole form inline. But I want only first name & last name fields next to each other.

```html
<form action="https://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
  <input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D0E000000DlzH">
  <input type=hidden name="recordType" value="01224000000B8m0">
  <input type=hidden name="00N1o00000Jsr1R" value="-">
  <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://www.maximo.ae/">
  <label for="salutation">Salutation</label>
  <select id="salutation" name="salutation" required>
    <option value="">--None--</option>
    <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
    <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
    <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
    <option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>
  </select><br>
  <label for="first_name">First Name</label><input placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required /><br>
  <label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input placeholder="Last Name" id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required /><br>
  <label for="company">Company</label><input placeholder="Company" id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" required /><br>
  <label for="phone">Phone Number</label><input placeholder="Phone No" id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" required /><br>
  <label for="email">Work mail</label><input placeholder="Email" id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" required /><br> Kindly identify your area of interest?
  <select id="00N0E00000HLPfA" name="00N0E00000HLPfA" title="Area of interest" required>
    <option value="">--None--</option>
    <option value="Job Opportunities">Job Opportunities</option>
    <option value="Solutions/Services">Solutions/Services</option>
    <option value="Vendor Partnership">Vendor Partnership</option>
  </select><br>
  <label for="lead_source">How did you hear about us?</label>
  <select id="lead_source" name="lead_source" required>
    <option value="">--None--</option>
    <option value="Advertisements / Marketing Campaigns">Advertisements / Marketing Campaigns</option>
    <option value="Events and Conferences">Events and Conferences</option>
    <option value="Magazines / Publications">Magazines / Publications</option>
    <option value="Referrals / Word-of-mouth">Referrals / Word-of-mouth</option>
    <option value="Telemarketing">Telemarketing</option>
    <option value="Web search (Google, Yahoo, etc)">Web search (Google, Yahoo, etc)</option>
    <option value="Social Media (LinkedIn, Facebook, etc.)">Social Media (LinkedIn, Facebook, etc.)</option>
  </select><br>
  <label for="description">Your Message</label><textarea name="description"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I am attaching an image below, I want these 2 next to each other [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0roF.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you notice in the code, the `<br>` tag stands for line break. Kindly remove it. I would suggest you to learn the basics of HTML before asking these questions, though.

```
<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required /><!-- br -->
<!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
<label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input placeholder="Last Name" id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required /><br>
```

Comment: Yes this worked thank you soo much for your help. Actually i'm new in this HTML so i didnt saw this small error

Comment: @SatvinderKaur Yes, I guessed that, and that's why I asked you to check some basic information about HTML. To know more about the tag, see [`<br>`: The Line Break element - HTML: HyperText Markup Language - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).